# Typescript type operators: translate an object type into a union

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a some typescript type-level oeprator (i.e., compile time) that extracts the type of all fields of a given type. For instance, given this type `{x: string, y: number}` I want to apply some type operator to it (`ExtractValueType<{x: string, y: number}>`) which will "return" a union type of `string | number`.

```
type Foo = {x: string, y:  number}
type Bar = ExtractValueType<Foo> // yields Bar = string | number


type ExtractValueType<T> = ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
type ExtractValueType<T> = T[keyof T]
```